# Using a class only with its header file in C++ in a plugins-load structure

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

These are some definitions and I want to implement a plugin structure.
A demo plugin-class:

```
// democlass.h
#include "DemoClass.h"
#include "include/plugins/v1/BaseClass.h"
#include "include/plugins/v1/PluginAgent.h"
#include "Poco/ClassLibrary.h"
class DemoClass : public BaseClass{
public:
    explicit DemoClass() : BaseClass(){
    }
    ~DemoClass() override;
    std::string Agent(PluginAgent* agent) override;
};
```

And its source file:

```
//democlass.cpp

DemoClass::~DemoClass() {
}
std::string DemoClass::Agent(PluginAgent* agent){
    agent->GetRelativePluginRef("democlass2");
    return "";
}

POCO_BEGIN_MANIFEST(BaseClass)
        POCO_EXPORT_CLASS(DemoClass)
POCO_END_MANIFEST
```

This is PluginAgent:

```
//PluginAgent.h
#include "BaseClass.h"
class BaseClass;

class PluginAgent{
public:
    PluginAgent() = default;
    BaseClass* GetRelativePluginRef(const std::string& pluginsName);
}
```

What I want is get other plugin pointer and use it, however, when I compile it, I get error for Unknown symbol `GetRelativePluginRef` which means I need to include the Agent.cpp. But the Agent.cpp will include other source file, which means I need to include the whole framework files.

what I want is just to include Agent head file only and Agent instance will be passed to the plugin through `std::string Agent(PluginAgent* agent)` method when framework loads the plugin.

Comment: You seem to be conflating dependencies from compiling (with `#include`) and from linking.  Of course you have to ultimately link against the definition of `GetRelativePluginRef` eventually, even if only at runtime.